How can I make my VBA macro more efficient?
This is my first question on Stack Overflow, but the knowledge I have gained by reading other's posts and feedback is immeasurable.
Can someone take a look at the script below, and help me to make it more efficient? I cobbled together the below macro based on my research, mostly done on this site. An example of inefficiency based on my own review, is my multiple uses of "Activate". I have read plenty of posts frowning upon it's use, but in this instance, I'm not quite sure what I should replace it with.
I appreciate all of the help, and will make sure to provide feedback on any answers. Thanks in advance!
Sub Mass_Copy_Paste:

Option Explicit

Public Matl As Workbook
Public Cost As Workbook
Public Name As Workbook
Public ABC As Workbook

Public Source1 As Worksheet
Public Source2 As Worksheet
Public Source3 As Worksheet

Public Dest1 As Worksheet
Public Dest2 As Worksheet
Public Dest3 As Worksheet
Public Dest4 As Worksheet
Public Dest5 As Worksheet
Public Dest6 As Worksheet
Public Dest7 AS Worksheet
Public Dest8 As Worksheet
Public Dest9 As Worksheet
Public Dest10 As Worksheet

Public Filename1 As String
Public Filename2 As String
Public Filename3 As String

Public lr1 As Long
Public lr2 As Long
Public lr3 As Long
Public lr4 As Long

Public lc1 As Long 
Public lc2 As Long
Public lc3 As Long

Public ColumnNum1 As Long
Public ColumnNum2 As Long
Public ColumnNum3 As Long

Public Rng as Range
Public Pt As PivotTable
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Sub Mass_Copy_Paste

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set ABC = ThisWorkbook

Filename1 = "C:\Users\Documents\Testfile1.xlsx"
Filename2 = "C:\Users\Documents\Testfile2.xlsx"
Filename2 = "C:\Users\Documents\Testfile3.xlsx"

Set Matl = Workbooks.Open(Filename1)
Set Cost = Workbooks.Open(Filename2)
Set Name = Workbooks.Open(Filename3)

Set Source1 = Matl.Sheets("Report")
Set Source2 = Cost.Sheets("Report")
Set Source3 = Name.Sheets("Report")

Set Dest1 = ABc.Sheets("Report1")
Set Dest2 = ABc.Sheets("Report2")
Set Dest3 = ABc.Sheets("Report3")

Source1.Activate
with Source1
ColumnNum1 = cells(11, Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
End With

Source2.Activate
with Source2
ColumnNum2 = cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
End With

Source3.Activate
With Source3
ColumnNum3 = cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column

Dest1.Activate
Range(Cells(2, "A"),Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNum1).End(xlUp)).ClearContents

Dest2.Activate
Range(Cells(2, "A"),Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNum1).End(xlUp)).ClearContents

Dest3.Activate
Range(Cells(2, "A"),Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNum1).End(xlUp)).ClearContents

Source1.Activate
lr1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lc1 = Cells(11, Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
Range(Cells(12, 1), Cells(lr1, lc1)).Copy
Dest1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:= False

Source2.Activate
lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lc2 = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(lr2, lc2)).Copy
Dest1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:= False

Source3.Activate
lr3 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lc3 = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(lr3, lc3)).Copy
Dest1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:= False

Dest1.ACtivate
With Dest1
lr4 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlup).Row
Range("BW2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BW2:BW" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BX2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BX2:BX" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BY2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BY2:BY" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BZ2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BZ2:BZ" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CA2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CA2:CA" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CB2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CB2:CB" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CC2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CC2:CC" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CD2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CD2:CD" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CE2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CE2:CE" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CF2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CF2:CF" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CG2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CG2:CG" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CH2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CH2:CH" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CI2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CI2:CI" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
End With

Dest2.ACtivate
With Dest2
lr4 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlup).Row
Range("AZ2").Autofill Destination:= Range("AZ2:AZ" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BA2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BA2:BA" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BC2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BC2:BC" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BD2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BD2:BD" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BE2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BE2:BE" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BF2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BF2:BF" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("BG2").Autofill Destination:= Range("BG2:BG" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
End With

Dest3.ACtivate
With Dest3
lr4 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlup).Row
Range("CD2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CD2:CD" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CE2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CE2:CE" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CF2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CF2:CF" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CG2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CG2:CG" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CH2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CH2:CH" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CI2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CI2:CI" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CJ2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CJ2:CJ" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CK2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CK2:CK" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
Range("CL2").Autofill Destination:= Range("CL2:CL" & lr4), Type:= xlFillDefault
End With

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.CalculateFullRebuild

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub


You're using With but not scoping anything inside those blocks to the With.  If you did that then you wouldn't need those Activate's   See for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-with-statements

...also whenever you have variables with sequential numeric suffixes  (eg lr1, lr2, ... lrn) you probably want to take a look into using arrays instead.

Less about efficiency in execution:  A wall of declarations doesn't particularly help you trouble shoot.  If you had each declaration near/in-line with its first use it would help in the long run in case there are issues, and if you need to move/modify only portions of the script.

...plus all of those variables are Globals, which is only something you do if you absolutely need to. They should all be declared inside the Sub. Unless I mis-edited your code (you had two Sub Mass_Copy_Paste() lines in the code block, so I moved the first one out...)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thanks for all of the comments! I will try to implement the changes and provide feedback. There are some new concepts that I need to incorporate, so bear with me it may take a day or two.

Suggestions below.  Your code can be refactored to pull out repeated tasks and your "wall" of declarations is gone...
(compiled but not tested)
Option Explicit

Sub Mass_Copy_Paste()
    'use const for fixed values
    Const Filename1 As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Testfile1.xlsx"
    Const Filename2 As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Testfile2.xlsx"
    Const Filename3 As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Testfile3.xlsx"
    
    Dim Dest1 As Worksheet, Dest2 As Worksheet, Dest3 As Worksheet
    Dim ABC As Workbook
    
    OptimizePerformance   'turn on optimizations

    Set ABC = ThisWorkbook
    Set Dest1 = ABC.Sheets("Report1")
    Set Dest2 = ABC.Sheets("Report2")
    Set Dest3 = ABC.Sheets("Report3")

    CopySourceData Filename1, "Report", 11, Dest1
    CopySourceData Filename2, "Report", 6, Dest2
    CopySourceData Filename1, "Report", 6, Dest3
    
    FillDown Dest1.Range("BW2:CI2")
    FillDown Dest2.Range("AZ2:BA2,BC2:BG2")
    FillDown Dest3.Range("CD2:CL2")
    
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    
    OptimizePerformance False 'turn off optimizations

End Sub

Sub OptimizePerformance(Optional goFast As Boolean = True)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(goFast, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not goFast
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not goFast
    Application.EnableEvents = Not goFast
End Sub

'Copy data from file at `srcPath`, worksheet `srcSheet`, to sheet `wsDest`
'   Source header row is at `headerRow`
Sub CopySourceData(srcPath As String, srcSheet As String, headerRow As Long, wsDest As Worksheet)
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, arr, wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet
    
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(srcPath)
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(srcSheet)
    
    'clear destination sheet
    wsDest.Range("A2", wsDest.UsedRange.Cells(wsDest.UsedRange.Cells.count)).ClearContents
    
    'find size of data to be copied
    lr = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lc = wsSrc.Cells(headerRow, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'copy values directly
    With wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Cells(headerRow + 1, "A"), wsSrc.Cells(lr, lc))
        wsDest.Range("A2").Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
    'wbSrc.close false 'optional: close source
End Sub

'auto fill `rng` down to the last-occupied row in colA
Sub FillDown(rng As Range)
    Dim lr As Long, ws As Worksheet, a As Range
    
    Set ws = rng.Worksheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp) 'last row colA
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'in case `rng` is not contiguous
        a.AutoFill Destination:=a.Resize(1 + (lr - a.Row))
    Next a
End Sub

